Flutter app: PlatformException "permission denied for sending sms", despite sms permissions being enabled
I'm trying to make an app that reads and sends SMS messages (for my own use, so no App/Play Store rules apply)
I'm using the Flutter plugin sms_advanced
I am asking for permission for SMS access on app initialization, and I have double-checked in the phone settings that SMS permission is enabled once user allows access in-app. I also have SMS permissions listed in the AndroidManifest.xml file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <application
        (etc....)

When I send an SMS message to the phone I get a confirmation that it was received from this print statement:
_receiver.onSmsReceived?.listen((SmsMessage msg) {
  print("SMS received");
  _sendAutoReply(msg.address!);
});

...but the auto-reply code results in this error:
E/flutter (22966): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(#01, permission denied for sending sms, null, null)
E/flutter (22966): #0      JSONMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:170:7)
E/flutter (22966): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
E/flutter (22966): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22966): #2      SmsSender.sendSms (package:sms_advanced/sms_advanced.dart:354:7)
E/flutter (22966): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22966): 

...which is triggered by this line in the sms_advanced.dart file:
await _channel.invokeMethod("sendSMS", map);
...where channel has type MethodChannel
So basically: app requests SMS permissions, is granted them, this is reflected in Settings, READ_SMS is working as intended but SEND_SMS is not.
I'm just trying to make some sample code work for now; here is what I have:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:sms_advanced/sms_advanced.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late SmsReceiver _receiver;
  late SmsSender _sender;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Permission.sms.request().then((_) {
      _setupSmsListener();
    });
  }

  void _setupSmsListener() {
    _receiver = SmsReceiver();
    _sender = SmsSender();
    _receiver.onSmsReceived?.listen((SmsMessage msg) {
      print("SMS received");
      _sendAutoReply(msg.address!);
    });
  }

  void _sendAutoReply(String address) {
    // Define your automatic reply message
    String replyMessage = "Thank you for your message. We will get back to you soon.";

    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage(address, replyMessage);
    _sender.sendSms(message);
    message.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
        print("SMS is sent!");
      } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Fail) {
        print("Failed to send SMS!");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Auto SMS Reply App'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Listening for incoming SMS...'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


adding SEND_SMS permission in manifest is not enough for sending sms in android app. Your app must be the default messaging app, read here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers
